# Can't make outlet to custom class from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, iboutlet

I am unable to make an @IBOutlet to my custom class from the elements in my prototype cell. I tried dragging from the element to the class; I let go of the blue line, and nothing happens.

[Here are my files](https://github.com/ghostpotato/SE-UILabel-Nil) if you want to poke around.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the issue:

[image: Missing Custom Class Name]

Changing to this should fix this problem:

[image: Provided Custom Class Name]

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I overlooked this. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Thank you!! Was searching for over an hour.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes, some xcode tricks 'n hacks work, for example:

- removing class name in storyboard for a cell;
- restarting xcode;
- cleaning project;
- removing outlets and trying to prepare them again;
- adding outlets using various techniques (ctrl+drag from storyboard, drag from an outlet defined in class file, drag from outlets tab - 'add new outlet')
- removing cell class inheritance, then adding outlet, then adding inheritance back again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `CustomtableViewCell` class is a Cocoa Touch Class file and not a swift file